Perform different action with value from columnB when it's the last row with the same ID in columnA
Each time when the last row (or only row) of the same ID before next one, or in last row, it should perform additional print task.
Please use the Openpyxl library preferably.
No need to write in excel, just read the values from it.



ID
Value




111/111
A1


222/222
B1


222/222
B8


222/222
B3


333/333
C4


333/333
C1


444/444
D4



The print result should read:
111/111  
repeats 3 x print: A1  
...here will be some additional job...  
222/222  
repeats 3 x print: B1  
repeats 3 x print: B8  
repeats 3 x print: B3  
...here will be some additional job...  
333/333  
repeats 3 x print: C4  
repeats 3 x print: C1  
...here will be some additional job...  
444/444  
repeats 3 x print: D4  
...here will be some additional job...

end of the program




This is the outcome from the current scrip I have:

ID: 111/111

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Pokus: 1 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: A1
----------------x
Pokus: 2 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: A1
----------------x
Pokus: 3 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: A1
----------------x
Program pokračuje

ID: 222/222

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Pokus: 1 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: B1
----------------x
Pokus: 2 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: B1
----------------x
Pokus: 3 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: B1
----------------x
Program pokračuje

ID: 222/222

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Pokus: 1 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: B8
----------------x
Pokus: 2 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: B8
----------------x
Pokus: 3 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: B8
----------------x
Program pokračuje

ID: 222/222

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Pokus: 1 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: B3
----------------x
Pokus: 2 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: B3
----------------x
Pokus: 3 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: B3
----------------x
Program pokračuje

ID: 333/333

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Pokus: 1 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: C4
----------------x
Pokus: 2 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: C4
----------------x
Pokus: 3 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: C4
----------------x
Program pokračuje

ID: 333/333

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Pokus: 1 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: C1
----------------x
Pokus: 2 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: C1
----------------x
Pokus: 3 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: C1
----------------x
Program pokračuje

ID: 444/444

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Pokus: 1 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: D4
----------------x
Pokus: 2 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: D4
----------------x
Pokus: 3 / 3
Toto je prvá hodnota: D4
----------------x
Program pokračuje
Finished processing all rows.

Here is my simplified code so far:
import time
import openpyxl

# Link na súbor v exceli
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(
    'file_path')

# Aktívny hárok v exceli
sheet = wb['sheet1']

# Start z druhého riadku (hlavičky)
row_num = 2

previous_valueRČ = None
print_values = True

while row_num <= sheet.max_row:
    try:
        current_valueRČ = sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=2).value
        value_ŠUKL = sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=3).value
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Problem reading value in cell: {e}")

    print("")        
    print(f"ID: {current_valueRČ}")    

    if current_valueRČ != previous_valueRČ or not print_values:
        # Reset printing flag and print new ID if necessary
        print_values = True
        if current_valueRČ != previous_valueRČ:
            print("")
            print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
            #print(f"Rodné číslo: {current_valueRČ}")

        # Východzia pozícia pre 3x opakovanie ŠUKL a určenie status ak sa hodnoty zhodujú
            pokusy = 0
            match_found = False
            
            # Vnútorný loop pre repeat ŠUKL 3x
            while pokusy < 3 and not match_found:
                # Vytlačí číslo pokusu z troch opakovaní
                print(f"Pokus: {pokusy + 1} / 3")
                print(f"Toto je prvá hodnota: {value_ŠUKL}")

                # Statusy pre určenie zhody
                status1 = ("MATCH")
                status2 = ("NO MATCH")
                progr_pokr_True = ">>> Program pokračuje..."
                progr_pokr_Presk = "Položka nebola 3x nájdená; PRESKAKUJEM !!!"
                progr_pokr_False = ">>> Opakujem položku..."

                # Ukončenie sekcie výstupu (print) jednej položky
                print("----------------x")

                # Move to the next row ŠUKL (OK)
                # Interval pokusov musí byť na tejto intendácii!!!(5)
                pokusy += 1

            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Program pokračuje")

            # Update printing flag after successful printing
            if value_ŠUKL is not None:
                1
                print_values = False  # Stop printing for this ID if a value is found

            # Posúva sa na ďalšie RČ (OK)
            row_num += 1

#Zavrie excelovský súbor
wb.close()

# Exit the program
print("Finished processing all rows.")


The code looks incomplete because I don't see anything that reassigns the value of the previous row. The code would be easier to read if you use the API: for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=3, values_only=True)

You need to be clearer about what it is you are trying to achieve and with your data. You mention Columns A and B in the Title but your code seems to be referring to data from Columns B and C
